# div content editable with placeholder

Tags: html, css, angular, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I am trying to create a editor like LinkedIn create post component. There I want to keep non removable `<p><br></p>` content like below.

```
<div #mainEditor contenteditable="true"><p><br></p></div>
```

Also want to show a placeholder when editor has no value. Just inspect LinkedIn editor and see my scenario. I have no idea and unable to figured out how to keep non removable `<p><br></p>` with a placeholder.

Could anyone has an idea how they are doing that?

[image]

Comment: data-attribute + `:empty` and `::before`  CSS selector will help you here

Comment: didn't work that with <p><br></p> content inside div, I want to show place holder without removing <p><br></p> content. Also want to make <p><br></p> non removable.

Comment: a regular  placeholder shows when there is nothing at all. that is the initial purpose.  even your p is not empty filled with a br

Comment: I tried like this, didn't work

<div  contenteditable="true" placeholder="this div is actually empty, you can insert content here."><p><br></p></div>


div:empty::before {
  content:attr(placeholder);
  color:gray
}

Comment: :empty works if you have : `<div contenteditable="true" placeholder="this div is actually empty, you can insert content here."></div>`. this not the case, the p inside cannot either be used since it holds a tag (not empty either) .  example https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/hzLIE

Comment: Here is a work around https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eYJYKKJ but not really smart.